# grunt is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: gruntjs

**Hi guys,**
I really need help with Grunt installation on windows 7.
I have node v6.9.2 installed and also I did install `npm install -g grunt-cli`
I create package.json with `npm init` then `npm install` 
finally `npm install grunt --save-dev` and I add configuration to Gruntfile.js installed `npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev` and run `grunt`
I changed the User vaiables it didn't work.

```
C:\Users\MUB\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing `grunt` globally?

Comment: Well yes I installed and unstalled grunt many times to get to work but every time it failed.

Comment: If this is still a problem, try running `echo %PATH%` and see what's in there. It is probably as simple as the npm global module installation folder not being in the Windows search path.